# How can I make this python code look cleaner?

Tags: python

I was trying to practice what I've been learning so I had this idea and it covered most of what I've learned. The code works well but I hope if anyone can take a look and let me know how I can make it better.

```
print("available operations (*, +, /, -)\n\"delete\" to delete every previous calculations\n \"exit\" to stop the program ")

is_running = True
op = ""

while is_running:
    try:
        num1 = float(input(">> "))
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError")
        continue
    while is_running:
        op = input(">> ")
        if op == "exit":
            is_running = False
            break
        elif op == "delete":
            break

        try:
            num2 = float(input(">> "))
        except ValueError:
            print("ValueError")
            continue

        if op == "*":
            num1 = num1 * num2
            print(num1)
        elif op == "+":
            num1 = num1 + num2
            print(num1)
        elif op == "-":
            num1 = num1 - num2
            print(num1)
        elif op == "/":
            num1 = num1 / num2
            print(num1)
        else:
            print("unavailable operator")
            break
```

Comment: This is most likely a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but you can replace your operator conditionals with a dictionary lookup.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to replace the conditionals for operators with dictionary look up as mentioned in below code:

```
import  operator

def calculate(op, num1, num2):
    oper = {
        '+': operator.add,
        '-': operator.sub,
        '*': operator.mul,
        '/': operator.truediv
    }
    try:
        return oper[op](num1, num2)
    except KeyError:
        return 'Invalid Operator'

num1 = 40
num2 = 50
op = '*'
print(calculate(op, num1, num2))
```

One more thing is that you need not use multiple try-except statements. Only one statement for all the inputs is enough. There is also no need for while loop in the second input statement.

Comment: oh thank you, this looks much better. i didn't know about the operator module